# Turning a variable containing the number of months to X Years, X Months format?

Tags: php, date, time, relative-date

This is a bit like the popular relative time (ago) except I'm not dealing with a timestamp but the number of months.

I'm not sure on how to go by this though?

Heres some examples to improve your understanding of my question:

**If input was:**

> 3

**Output would be:**

> 3 Months

**If input was:**

> 13

**Output would be:**

> 1 Year, 1 month

So for every 12 months its X Year(s) (if any) and then the remaining months are following it with X month(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mod operator to get remaining months:

```
$years = (int)($total_months / 12);
$months = $total_months % 12;
```